# How to create object files with swift compiler from c source

Tags: swift

Using the [latest swift snapshot](https://swift.org/download/#latest-development-snapshots), when I run `swift -help` I see `-Xcc <arg> Pass <arg> to the C/C++/Objective-C compiler`.

My end goal is to create a static lib. How do I create an object file with the swift tools?

I tried this `swift -Xcc -c -Xcc MyCFile.c -Xcc -o -Xcc myObjectFile.o` but it just fires up the REPL.